# Activate the Num Lock indicator in the Status Bar

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, vba

How to detect Num lock indicator is active in excel...

Or enable num lock indicator in status bar

Comment: I know ... If it solves my queries .. I will definitely  accept..

Comment: +1 Good question :) Had me baffled for quite sometime :)

Comment: Not sure why this was closed; this certainly relates to programming in the sense that the correct answer would show whether it is programmatically possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John, As far as I know (and I could be wrong) but the `Application.Statusbar` doesn't give you the option to interact with it the way that you want.

I am not aware of any APIs as well that could achieve what you want. So till the time someone else comes and posts a method (if there is one), the answer to your question is

"It Cannot be Done"

HTH

Comment: I also tried but didn't find any solution.
Thanks to every one who replied...

Comment: @John: ... equals "Accept this answer".

Answer (score 1):

You're tagging your question as C#, so I think you're developing a C# app.
Within it you can use

```
if (Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock))
```

to detect if NumLock is on or not.

To set Num-Lock you could use

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);
private void PressKb(Keys keyCode)
{
    const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
    const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;

    keybd_event((byte)keyCode, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
    keybd_event((byte)keyCode, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
}
```

and with it

```
PressKb(Keys.NumLock);
```

Comment: Thaks for your reply....
I want to enable numlock indicator of excels status bar

Comment: @John: take a look at my edited answer. You're welcome :)

Comment: @John: numlock indicator on excel statusbar is on if in your system NUMLOCK is on; so if you simulate to press that key, the indicator will become on too!!

Comment: May be you are not getting my point...
right click ur status bar in excel a pop to customize status bar will appear .. In that pop up check num lock....
I want to detect whether that num lock is checked or not (which shows num lock in status bar).
Sorry for any  inconvenience...

Answer (score 0):

You could just see if num-lock is active, as surely the indicator only shows when it's active anyway. If you need to do this in VBA (Solution taken from [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/can-excel-vba-detect-if-caps-lock-num-lock-t2269371.html)).

```
'put these declarations at the top of the module
Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long)
As Integer
Private Const kNumlock = 144
```

And where you need it:

```
Public Function NumLock() As Boolean
NumLock = KeyState(kNumlock)
End Function

Private Function KeyState(lKey As Long) As Boolean
KeyState = CBool(GetKeyState(lKey))
End Function
```